# What is this piece of code for? (Just Curious)

Tags: javascript

This is just a question out of sheer curiosity, I'm not looking for help fixing anything, I just want to know what a specific piece of code is for.

So here's the full function that I've seen for a countdown timer:

```
countdown('countdown', 0, 30);

function countdown(element, mins, secs) {
    var time = mins * 60 + secs;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var display = document.getElementById(element);
        // Setting green for initial startup
        if(time == 30) {
            document.getElementById(element).style.color = "green";
        }
        // Setting yellow for the halfway point
        if(time == 15) {
            document.getElementById(element).style.color = "goldenrod";
        }
        // Setting red for the final 5 seconds
        if(time == 5) {
            document.getElementById(element).style.color = "red";
        }
        // If the timer reaches 0...
        if(time == 0) {
            document.getElementById(element).style.color = "black";
            display.innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
            // Game ends if countdown ends, give results just like above if game was finished
            alert("Quiz complete! You got " + totalCorrect + " correct out of 10.");
            return;
        }
        var mins = Math.floor(time / 60);
        if(mins < 10) mins = "0" + mins;
        var secs = time % 60;
        if(secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;
        var text = mins + ':' + secs;
        display.innerHTML = text;
        time--;
    }, 1000);
```

I'm just curious as to what that last line is for, I've never seen a value given after a brace before. What does that mean and what does that do?

Comment: In your case, it's simply a syntax error. Or wait, I'll get you some code formatting.

Comment: The very last line? The brace closes off the anonymous function block and the `1000` is the second arg to `setInterval`

Comment: It's the second parameter being passed to the `setInterval()` method on the fourth line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just curious as to what that last line is for, I've never seen a
>   value given after a brace before.

This is from the [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) method.

Its syntax looks like below.

`setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);`

The above line means Alert "Hello" every 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds).

In your case it's 1000 so it will recall it after 1 second.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! Was strange to me initially, I'm just starting out with Javascript so the sight itself was pretty new to me at the time.

Comment: It's OK. Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript)'s tutorial for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

its the time in milliseconds that the interval should run after (so in this case every second or thousand milliseconds).

```
   setTimeout(function(){
       //run this function every x milliseconds
   }, runEveryXMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function `setInterval` is defined with the following signature:

```
setInterval(callback, interval[, param1, param2, ...])
```

Where `callback` represents a function and `interval` represents how often you want the `callback` to run. Rather than declaring the function out of line, and passing it into this function the writer of this code opted to create an anonymous function and create it right inline with this function call.

A nice way to view this is by collapsing the contents of the first argument:

```
setInterval(function() { ... }, 1000);
```

so that this way we can easily see how this is a call to `setInterval`.

More info on `setInterval` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

This code is for pushing countdown timer to the DOM element. Have a loot at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mS56t/).

When the time is less than 15 seconds it updates the dom that time is expiring by defining the color as `goldenrod`. When the time is below 5 seconds it updates the dom about the same timer but with the color as `red`.

Basically the magic is done by `setInterval()`, which loops for every second and update the DOM about the timer